# How to avoid classloading issues with MyBatis in OSGI environment?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, mybatis

I am working on an Eclipse 3.7 RCP-based application with multiple modules. Module A is a bunch of libraries including mybatis-3.2.2.jar. Module B depends on module A (Require-Bundle in the manifest.mf) and has code that uses MyBatis to access data in a database. I have exported packages with mapper classes and XML in module B and imported them in module A. I am building SqlSessionFactory in the code, and it works fine if I add all Mapper classes by name, e.g.

```
configuration.addMapper(MyMapper.class);
```

however when I try to add all Mappers in the package:

```
configuration.addMappers(MyMapper.class.getPackage().getName());
```

MyBatis does not see them.

I tried changing the default classloader but this did not help.

```
Resources.setDefaultClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

I suspect the problem has to do with visibility of classes in an OSGI environment. If that's the case, are there any ways to fix it in the application?

Comment: in addition, you may want to file a bug with mybatis because they are using ResolverUtil in a way that doesn't even allow you to provide your own classloader without having to re-write the scanning code. At least how it looks immediately.

Comment: I found this link and it worked for me nicely http://techtwitch.blogspot.de/2012/06/boldly-go-where-no-sql-mapper-has-gone.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

`Resources.setDefaultClassLoader(Activator.class.getClassLoader())`. I think that will use the OSGi class loader for the bundle. Hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 1):

configuration.addMappers uses its own ResolverUtil that uses the Thread context class loader. (At least in mybatis3).

Best bet would be to write your own scanning code and use addMapper directly. There are my references and examples below:

> http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mybatis/mybatis/3.1.1/org/apache/ibatis/session/Configuration.java?av=f#518
>
> http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mybatis/mybatis/3.1.1/org/apache/ibatis/io/ResolverUtil.java#148

EDIT: Here are some for mybatis 3.2.2

> http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mybatis/mybatis/3.2.2/org/apache/ibatis/io/ResolverUtil.java#147
>
> http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mybatis/mybatis/3.2.2/org/apache/ibatis/binding/MapperRegistry.java#86

Same thing applies, though.

Comment: I came to a similar conclusion. I can see ResolverUtil.find(Test test, String packageName) method not even using the classloader field, instead delegating to VFS.list(path). I presume I'd have to write a custom VFS class implementing OSGI-specific scanning logic. Not worth the effort for me, I'll keep adding my Mapper classes one by one.

Comment: Even though your links maybe redirecting the person to the correct answer, it is better you explain them out over here, because over time you never know if the links are still up and functioning or no. Thanks. @Sheena Artip

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem with Spring Data JPA in a Felix OSGi environment. In that case I was able to override a factory class and add this into the offending methods:

```
ClassLoader pre = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
try {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(context.getClassLoader());
    // add mappers here or call super method
} finally {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(pre);
}
```

In this case "context" was a Spring context, but you should be able to get Module B's classloader from a BundleWiring.

```
Bundle bundle; //get this by symbolic name if you don't have a reference
BundleWiring bundleWiring = bundle.adapt(BundleWiring.class);
bundleWiring.getClassLoader();
```

Hopefully the addMappers method doesn't need to access Module A's classloader in the same call. If that's the case, there's not a ton you'll be able to do unless there's a way to extend and inject a different Configuration or MapperRegistry class.